# Moodle - Redirect New Users to Original URL (wantsurl) after profile update

Tags: php, moodle

Links to my online courses are posted on various websites. The link look like this : https://example.com/course/view.php?id=31

When new users click on the link, they are brought to my Moodle website login page.

When they sign-up on my Moodle site with Google authentication, they are taken to the form where they need to fill up  a couple of custom fields.

After they fill in the custom fields and submit, they are taken to preferences.php

Instead of the preferences.php, I need them to go to the original URL, which is stored in "wantsurl"

Right now, I have just edited the preferences.php and used a simple redirect to send users to the dashboard page.

What code can I add to the preferences.php page to redirect users to the original URL that they want to go to? i.e. "wantsurl"

Note: If I remove the custom fields, users are redirected to the course page (wantsurl) after authentication. But the custom fields are essential.